# porting from solaris to linux?

Tags: linux, ipsec

I am working on ipsecconf command ,by using  ipsecconf -a we can Add the IPsec policy to the system as specified  by  each  entry  in the file.now i want equivalent command in linux.

eg of ipsecconf in solaris:

```
$ipsecconf -a
$ ipsecconf -l (Listing of the internal system policy table)
#INDEX 9
{ rport telnet dir out } ipsec { encr_algs des-cbc(64) encr_auth_algs hmac-md5(128) sa shared }
#INDEX 10
{ rport telnet dir out } ipsec { encr_algs des-cbc(64) encr_auth_algs hmac-md5(128) sa shared }
#INDEX 11
{ rport telnet dir in } ipsec { encr_algs des-cbc(64) encr_auth_algs hmac-md5(128) sa shared }
#INDEX 12
{ rport telnet dir in } ipsec { encr_algs des-cbc(64) encr_auth_algs hmac-md5(128) sa shared }
```

Comment: Is there a question here ? That deals with programming ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ipsec` is the answer you are looking for.

**Synopsis**

```
ipsec command [ argument ...]

ipsec --help
ipsec --version
ipsec --versioncode
ipsec --copyright
ipsec --directory
ipsec --confdir
```

[Here's](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipsec) the complete man for that.

Comment: above is for solaris,there is no man page for ipsec in linux... i need in linux

Comment: Sir, the 'above' is for Linux and not for Solaris. You may not have binaries of ipsec in your Linux box and that's why you're not getting it.